# smalldatetime field DB inserted with 01/01/1900 00:00:00

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I wish to insert a smalldatetime(DB) field value with c#, i used this code

```
 dataAdapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO journal_jour (id_emp, date, montant_acompte, heur_travaille, Absence) VALUES        (" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "," + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() + "," + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "," + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "," + ch + ")"
        , con);
```

but the field in DB is always filled with a default value: 01/01/1900 00:00:00, when i used a breackpoint to check its value, it's well done, for example for today its value is '22/04/2012' 
And thank you in advance.

Comment: try to change the datatype in the database to datatime.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your field is of DateTime type in database, you could do the following. It is for just inserting date in the table, [**you should always use parameter in SQL**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO <table> (<column>) VALUES (@value)", connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToShortDateString()));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: problem solved, i added ' ' to the value of the date                                                    dataAdapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO journal_jour (id_emp, date, montant_acompte, heur_travaille, Absence) VALUES        (" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + ",'" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() + "'," + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "," + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "," + ch + ")"
            , con);

Comment: @user1348165, oh yes. But go for parameterized query

Comment: @user1348165 plus, aways go for parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use SqlParameters. You will get two results.
 - Prevent SQL Injection Attacks
 - No need to worry about delimiters for each data type

```
string queryText = "INSERT INTO journal_jour " +    
                   "(id_emp, date, montant_acompte, heur_travaille, Absence) " +   
                   "VALUES (@id_emp, @dtValue, @montant, @heur,@absence)";   

dataAdapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(queryText, con);
dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_emp",comboBox1.SelectedValue);
dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtValue",dateTimePicker1.Value.Date);
dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@montant",textBox2.Text.Trim());
dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@heur",textBox1.Text.Trim());
dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@absence",ch);
```

Comment: well explained, i should learn ORM technologie to handle this problem with sql